Julia Pkg aborts (signal 6) when trying to install "Plots". Am I doing something wrong and how to fix that?
Here is screenshot just for colored syntax:

I use manjaro linux x86_64
$ lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: ManjaroLinux
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:        24.1.2
Codename:       Xahea

I have tried to install julia:

via pacman from official repositories;
via curl ... | sh from julia installation tutorial;
via juliaup from AUR;
via juliaup github releases binary download.

Tried julia version 1.8.5 and latest release. Tried cleaning ~/.julia multiple times.
In every case import Pkg; Pkg.add("Plots"); (and other variants of installing it) shows error "Error: curl_multi_assign: 1", then aborts entire julia shell. I tried a few other packages and they seem to install fine. Only the "Plots" seem to have an issue.
If it is related, here is my curl version:
$ curl --version
curl 8.10.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/8.10.1 OpenSSL/3.3.2 zlib/1.3.1 brotli/1.1.0 zstd/1.5.6 libidn2/2.3.7 libpsl/0.21.5 libssh2/1.11.0 nghttp2/1.63.0 nghttp3/1.5.0
Release-Date: 2024-09-18
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ipfs ipns mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTP3 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM PSL SPNEGO SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd

Here is full crash output in text form:
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.10.5 (2024-08-27)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  
|__/                   |

(@v1.10) pkg> status
Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.10/Project.toml`
  [682c06a0] JSON v0.21.4
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.40.9
  [e99dba38] Qt6Wayland_jll v6.7.1+1

(@v1.10) pkg> update
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General.toml`
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.10/Project.toml`
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.10/Manifest.toml`
┌ Warning: attempting to remove probably stale pidfile
│   path = "/home/ussur/.julia/compiled/v1.10/Plots/ld3vC_aAiQW.ji.pidfile"
└ @ FileWatching.Pidfile /usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.10/FileWatching/src/pidfile.jl:244
Precompiling project...
┌ Error: curl_multi_assign: 1                        ]  0/2
└ @ Downloads.Curl /usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.10/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:57
┌ Error: curl_multi_assign: 1
└ @ Downloads.Curl /usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.10/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:57

[57538] signal (6.-6): Aborted
in expression starting at none:0
unknown function (ip: 0x7771d1ae63f4)
gsignal at /lib/libc.so.6 (unknown line)
abort at /lib/libc.so.6 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x7771d1023dab)
uv_run at /lib/julia/libjulia-internal.so.1.10 (unknown line)
ijl_task_get_next at /lib/julia/libjulia-internal.so.1.10 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x7771b7f29e84)
unknown function (ip: 0x7771b7ba3b4e)
unknown function (ip: 0x7771b84668c7)
unknown function (ip: 0x7771b80658ac)
unknown function (ip: 0x7771b81f8971)
unknown function (ip: 0x7771b8479058)
unknown function (ip: 0x7771b826fc66)
unknown function (ip: 0x7771d10632dc)
Allocations: 7757925 (Pool: 7743604; Big: 14321); GC: 10
zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)  julia

UPD: Also, curl -fsSL https://install.julialang.org | sh just instantly segfaults when I try to add any packages. And AUR package juliaup-bin just segfaults even when I try to do status in pkg mode.

This looks like a problem with curl getting to the Julia download site. You could try installing or updating curl on your system and see if that helps.
